# How to run @RunWith(Cucumber.class) step by step

Tags: java, junit, cucumber, bdd, cucumber-jvm

I'm working on a BDD file and trying to test with JUnit.

I want to use RunCukesTest class with @RunWith(Cucumber.class).

I've searched on many websites about how to install requirements, but I couldn't find any website which explains it briefly, step by step.

Could you explain me briefly, step by step, how can I run my test?

```
package test.newtest;

import cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCukesTest {
}
```

Comment: When you have put your feature file? It has to be found in same package as the RunCukesTest class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Will, because of nobody answered me for a long time, I've found it by asking to other people.

Answer (score 1):

Cucumber will default to looking for feature files under the same package as RunCucksTest. You can also change the location(s) it will look for feature files by supplying the "features" option with the `@CucumberOptions` annotation (in RunCucksTest). E. g.,

```
@CucumberOptions(strict = true,  features = {
        "src/test/resources/cucumber/",
    },monochrome=true)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Set break points at where you want to trace in
2. Right click on the Test Runner
3. Select Debug as JUnit.